# UDP commands for Linux and Mac?

Tags: android, linux, osx, udp

I'm trying to test UDP between 2 terminals in the same machine.

For instance:

**Terminal 1**

- UDP listener@port:3000
- UDP sender to port:3001

**Terminal 2**

- UDP listener@port:3001
- UDP sender to port:3000

and testing the above under the environment - MacOSX terminal and Linux Terminal (Android Emulators).

Anyone knows command for this?

I've googled and found `nc` for UNIX, but for OSX

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nc.1.html

```
$ nc                                                                     [~]
usage: nc [-46AcCDdFhklMnOortUuvz] [-K tc] [-b boundif] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
      [-s source_ip_address] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
```

It seems that `nc` does not have `-u` option for UDP.

---

EDIT:
I've got answers that suggest the OSX `nc` does have `-u` option.

Having said that. Aside from this Question, here's what I've done as the final approarch;

**For OSX:**

I use node.js instead of Shell commands for these UDP testing. This is much more powerful and comfortable to me.

**For Android(Linux):**

I prepared a test Android App project to test.
Clone the project, and open the identical projects, and run 2 identical instances(emulators).

Just for future references.

Comment: I can see a tiny u there: `nc [-....u..]`

Comment: Thanks. Reading the dev apple page throughly, it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X's `nc` does have a `-u` option, which tells it to use UDP. The only tricky thing is that you have to run two instances of `nc -u` on each terminal, one sending and one listening; and since one (generally the listener) will be in the background, using control-C to exit it will only exit for foreground instance; you have to kill the background one explicitly. This should do it:

```
nc -u -l 3000 & nc -u localhost 3001; kill $!
```

...then just reverse the port numbers on the other terminal. When you kill the foreground (sending) `nc`, it'll execute the `kill $!` and clean up the listener as well.