# What is the counterpart of telnet client for servers based on UDP?

Tags: telnet, udp

Telnet client is said to communicate only with servers which are based on TCP, not with those on UDP. What is the counterpart of telnet client for servers based on UDP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UDP commands for Linux and Mac?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112394/udp-commands-for-linux-and-mac)

Answer (score 6):

Pedantically, a Telnet client is a client for [the Telnet protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), which is a TCP/IP-based protocol with no UDP-based equivalent.

However, `telnet` programs are also commonly used with non-Telnet servers, *e.g.* to debug HTTP or SMTP connections (as demonstrated in [the Wikipedia article on Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Modern_day_uses)). Many equivalents exist, supporting both TCP and UDP; the most common one is probably [Netcat](https://nc110.sourceforge.io/) or one of its descendants such as [Ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/) and [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

[UDP commands for Linux and Mac?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112394/86440) gives an example using `nc` (Netcat) for bi-directional UDP communications.